# Content Query WebPart missing in SharePoint 2013

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

I was working with CQWP and after a while I had a lot of Content Query Web Parts on my masterpage, I deleted all and later found out that I couldnt see/access Content Query Web Parts under Content Rollup.

My Sharepoint server publishing service is already activated. Please what went wrong.

```
Edit: I just found out that I mistakenly deleted contentquery.webpart from web part gallery. 

How can I rectify this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in the site's recycle bin, just restore it from there.

Comment: yes, you are right, though I had to export another CQWP from another site collection and upload again before seeing this answer. I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now you know what to do next time in this situation ;)

Comment: yes I do, next on my agenda is how to apply a custom masterpage for my subsite in sp2013

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can populate Content Query web part in gallery again.

Go to Web part gallery click on New Document  in ribbon, click new and select Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart from Gallery and populate it.

Comment: @KoredeLawrenceOluwafemi: I am glad that it helped. Please mark it as answer so that this answer can help others.. :)